Why are True and False both Primitives?
I am new to Logic. I was going through Derek Goldrei's book Propositional and Predicate Calculus: A Model of Argument.
Why do we need False as Primitive?--It can easily be derived from True using Negation(Primitive).
Is it because it'll lead to Paradox?--If False is derived from True, then it's something like, False needs True for its existence but its very existence means Absence of True;
if False exists, True can't but then without True, False can't exist either.
I don't know what I am talking about.

No paradox at all. But it is quite natural to think in terms of True/False: since our infancy we are trained to use both concepts.

@MauroALLEGRANZA thanks but as I said False can be derived as Negation of True, why take it as Primitive...

@MauroALLEGRANZA it'll take me time to understand your second comment because my intuition is just opposite as in True should be the Primitive... Thanks...

It's practical only. False is a randomal false proposition that's all.

Because not everything that is "not true" is automatically "false".
The "Law" of Noncontradiction first proposed by Aristotle has turned out to not be a Law but a Principle.   While logic typically follows this rule, it has too many exceptions to be considered a Law anymore.
For example, some statements makes no objective declaration so it is neither true nor false like Questions (How are you?) and Commands (Hand me the screwdriver.)  In Computer Science, there are also truthy and falsy operators which make an objective declaration (like NULL, NAN, ERROR, and Booleans) which caste to true or false to prevent software from crashing while not objectively being true or false; so, they are likewise Not True without being False.
Inversely, there are also statements and natural states that are simultaneously True and False; so, it would be incorrect to call them Not True even though they are False.  These include things like like Self-Referential Paradoxes (This sentence is a lie.), Quantum Superpositions (Schrodinger's Cat is Alive.), Semantic Dialetheisms (Corporations are people.), and Mathematical Dialetheisms (√4 = -2)
Because of these exceptions, we need to be able to differentiate False and Not True as two separate concepts even though we know that 99.9% of the time they will be bound by the Principle of Noncontradiction.

Amazing Answer, Thanks!!!!

From a strictly symbolic point ov view, we need False (⊥) and at least one connective: → (if..., then ...").
With them we define True (⊤) as ⊥ → ⊥ and negation: ¬A as A → ⊥.
You can see Yaroslav Shramko & ‎Heinrich Wansing, Truth and Falsehood: An Inquiry into Generalized Logical Values (2011).
Symbols apart, we can start with True and Negation as primitives, and then define False.
But our best intuition about negation is that it swaps True into False, and vice vers.
See Aristotle, Met. 1011b23:

we define what the true and the false are. To say of what is that it is not, or of what is not that it is, is false, while to say of what is
that it is, and of what is not that it is not, is true; so that he who says of anything that it is, or that it is not, will say either what is true or what is false.


+1 One advantage of defining "not" (¬A) as A → ⊥ is that this also accords with intuitionist logic. And it highlights a pretty subtle, philosophical problem with "not": How is it ever possible to derive something False (0=1) from any meaningful, non-contradictory proposition A? (Griss tried to start developing a negationless intuitionist mathematics. But he died relatively young and never got any followers.)

False is only a randomal false proposition, it's called false. But it's not the semantical falsehood. Right?

@mudskipper "How is it ever possible to derive something False (0=1) from any meaningful, non-contradictory proposition A?". Wow, that question never occurred to me or read anywhere.
I somehow feel Logic favours False, because I am having a very tough time understanding Implication. The question that's bugging me is HOW CAN something which is defined in terms of True Values (p-->q) be expressed as False values, -pVq and it's Equivalent too "Logically".

Can we not define False as (True-->Not True)-->⊥

@AshishShukla - if we have Not, why not False = Not True?

@MauroALLEGRANZA yes of course why not, it's just that True, intuitionally feels precursor to False. In either case my question was exactly about this, why take both as Primitives...

IMHO In formal logic the standard is that 'true' is 'not false' because for instance: I say that if p is true, then q is true stays as a true valued line in the Truth Table T T T. But when p is false it's not linked at all with the Truth Values of q, but despite that the conditional is true. The meaning of this is that it's not false to assume that a connection exits between p and q .

A sentence (assertion, indicative statement, proposition), p, is true if and only if it is the case that p. A statement, p, is false if and only if p is not true.
The above is a definition of the predicate "__ is true", to be applied to sentences. It shows that the predicate "__ is false" can be defined in terms of the predicate "__ is true" together with the logical operator "not" (indicating logical negation). So, in this sense, we only need one predicate. We could dispense with "__ is false".
Logic studies first of all what valid inferences are. It's then convenient to think of "being true" or "being false" as values, truth values, associated with sentences. A true sentence is seen as having the value True, while a false sentence (one that is not true) is seen as having the value False. True and False here are no more than two symbols - we could just as well replace them with 1 and 0, or 0 and 1, or +1 and -1, or T and F.
In other words, we just want to have a single symbol for each possible truth value. The fact that we want (and need) at least two symbols only indicates that we want to use the logical operator "not" in our sentences. In other words, we want to model both assertions and negations. Even if we would dispense with the predicate "__ is false", we would still want (and need) to use two truth values (in classical logic).

Our mind needs minimum two values to work, it can't work with just True. However for the sake of discussion, intuitively, what do you think came first, True or False... But as Mauro ALLEGRANZA said in his answer, it's the other way around, True is derived from False, but intuitionally it feels, True must come first, without True we cannot understand False...

On a purely logical level none of them "comes first". But "true" (in actual use) is used to refer to "the world" ("everything that is the case"). You might say, that cognition (or intuition) of some facts must "come first", and "only then" do we start using logic. Making a positive assertion (without using "not"), you refer to a definite fact. When you state "not A" you are in a way not making a determinate assertion about "the world" -- merely negating that A is part of the world. So, "not A" doesn't add "positive facts" to the world.

In other words, your question is a bit like wondering: "Here I have a sock. I see it. It is there, it is real. A real thing. Hm, there is a hole in my sock. A real big hole. It is really there. But a hole is a pure absence! It is nothing. It is not there. That's what a hole is. How can something that is a pure absence be something real? How can we even speak of it? What came first, the sock or the hole? The sock or everything that is not-sock? Being or nothingness? -- Oh, why did I ever think that studying philosophy was a good idea?"

You know guys, you know your stuff, I am finding my way here, being coherent while discussing such topics is an achievement for me. I am new to all this but somehow I started with The Anatomy of Mathematics and in the world of axioms where ideally I fancy everything must collapse into sigularity, when I see that in case of True and False, False can be derived from True then why take that as Primitive. It's convinient, yes, but I feel when I have seen enough examples of it, I'll also realise the "requirement"/"justification" as well but till then search continues...

When I'm not sure about some issue (which seems like a general, known issue, not a real original question), I sometimes ask ChatGPT for some names of people who have written about the issue. I then try to find relevant papers on scholar.googe.com, looking for those names. You'll find a lot of quick clarifications that way. Also, looking for relevant terms on plato.standford.edu (SEP) quickly will give pretty good background info (though sometimes opionated and not always reliable).

As Cantor wrote in his dissertation: "In re mathematica ars proponendi quaestionem pluris facienda est quam solvendi" -- "In mathematics the art of how to pose a question is more important than that of solving it." This applies even more so to philosophy.

"how to pose a question" is PRECISELY what I have set out to achieve. Many years back I was reading SE Mathematcis Questions and Answers and one thing that struck me was that Mathematicians talk differently and second how fluently they "TALK MATH"! In comments itself they would propose a system something like "I assume such and such, since, therefore" etc. and I was spellbound!!! So one of the main driving force behind me studying Math is to be able to Talk Fluently in Math. So HUGE HUGE THANKS to ALL LOGICIANS AND MATHEMATICIANS OUT THERE. Till then I may be little incoherent?!

Falsehood and negation are fundamentally different concepts.
False, along with true, is a truth value. It is semantic concept. In classical logic, a proposition may be true or false. Being able to speak about the truth or falsehood of a proposition is useful because it allows us to say of some proposition that it is true or false under some interpretation, or that it is true or false under all interpretations.
Negation can be thought of as an operation on a proposition that yields another proposition. It is a syntactic concept. It helps with specifying deductive rules.
This way of dividing up logic between the syntactic and semantic is very common. We can use soundness and completeness proofs to exhibit the relation between the two.
In classical logic, it is correct that if a proposition is true then its negation is false and if a proposition is false then its negation is true. But this does not hold in other logics. So when we think more generally about logical relations, it is important to distinguish between falsehood and negation.

I am not confusing between the two I am merely stating that False can be derived from True using Negation.

In classical logic, yes, but not in others.

@Bumble - Which other logics do you have in mind here? And would you say that in those other logics "negation" (or "not") has the same meaning as in classical logic or that because of giving it a different meaning, true is not flipped into false by negation?

@mudskipper There are 3-valued logics where the negation of false has the value not-false, but this differs from true. More generally, in any logic that is not bivalent, a proposition may be neither true nor false. Arguably, whenever you consider a different logic, the connectives have a different meaning. Intuitionistic negation is different from classical negation. But unlike Quine, I don't think it follows from this that non-classical logics are changing the subject.

Ok, I thought you meant that - but that's trivial, I'd say. (As to 'meaning' -- I'm not sure if I agree with Quine. But I think intuitionists will say that to them the 'meaning' of logical conjectives is different?)

As Mauro has pointed out:

No paradox at all. But it is quite natural to think in terms of True/False: since our infancy we are trained to use both concepts. – Mauro ALLEGRANZA

So, there are differences between logic and psychological primitives. A logical primitive is just part of a formal system. But a psychological primitive is part of the human conceptual system. But this can be a contentious statement. For instance, the great Frege was an anti-psychologist. From the article:

In logic, anti-psychologism (also logical objectivism1 or logical realism2) is a theory about the nature of logical truth, that it does not depend upon the contents of human ideas but exists independent of human ideas.

But, many contemporary philosophers reject this. One example is Robert Hanna (philpapers.org). He has written a book on the interrelation between the logical and the psychological called Rationality and Logic (GB). From the description:

An argument that logic is intrinsically psychological and human psychology is intrinsically logical, and that the connection between human rationality and logic is both constitutive and mutual... he defends the broadly Kantian thesis that all (and only) rational animals possess an innate cognitive "logic faculty." Hanna's claims challenge the conventional philosophical wisdom that sees logic as a fully formal or "topic-neutral" science...

Thus, you will not find a technical justification in formal systems for using true and not deriving false because the use of both as primitives is because it appeals to our intuitions (SEP) about logic. For those of us who reject logic floats around in the universe divorced from human thought like some magical force, we accept that logic is ultimately rooted in physical being (an idea called embodied cognition (SEP)). True and false as opposites appeals to an intuition that even small children readily understand in the same way they see addition and subtraction as fundamental opposites as opposed to addition and additive inverses. And the reason for this distinction is psychological, because all meaningful thought relies on intuitions.

This is the first time I don't feel inclined to upvote one of your answers. Psychologism is untenable, I think. All the old arguments by Pierce, Frege, Husserl against psychologism are still valid, imo.

@mudskipper lol Well, I salute your civility in disagreement. If you don't buy into physical computation or embodied and extended cognition, I certainly hold no malice towards your thinking. But I think cognitive science has done away with the notion that logical principles particularly when crafted with an eye on representing values is divorced from the broader notions of psychological cognition. In a nutshell, the effects of cognitive biases on logical ratiocination are just too pronounced to see the science of logic as...

anything other than an abstraction that willfully omits a heap of feelings, emotions, affect, and mood but does not entirely escape the orbit of non-logical cognition.

I do agree with that ... But still shrink back from the abyss of psychologism... :)

@mudskipper In deference to your gender-neutral wisdom, let me say that I am open to a contemporary riposte against the psychologism of Ned Block and those who follow who find that psychological principles undergird logical ones ultimately, and that I'm open to questioning how the abstraction of the logic of formal systems isn't simply a value-neutral expression of grammar, the outward appearance of the internal neurological structure of the brain. I've recently accepted that my attacks on historical mathematical realism might be ignorant of more contemporaneous categorical schemes...

Do you have a contemporary champion to recommend?

I'll see if I can find one. I'm still studying Pierce...

@mudskipper If you blanket reject psychologism, you get a larger can of worns than the one you chucked out — How on earth (or Plato's heaven) does logic arise at all? By the papal bull of Frege/Russell??

@Rushi - It doesn't arise. It just is. Almost like the world itself, but more real because more imaginary -- hahaha :)

I also think that logic is a normative science - or has some normative aspects (mathematics too, but no one ever seems to really speak about that).


I am new to Logic.

Welcome to the world that makes sense. The other one doesn't. It's run by monkeys that learned how to talk.

Why do we need False as Primitive?--It can easily be derived from True using Negation(Primitive).

Yes, false is just another name for the negation of something true. But everything else is also just shorthand for a simpler construct.
You can generate the integers from the null set, but it's easier to work with numbers than a long function of nothing.

I don't know what I am talking about.

Yes you do. And the fact that you asked this question here, on your own time (not homework), means you WILL understand it better than almost anyone. This  answer might very well appear in a future biography of a famous logician.
Just don't expect anyone outside academia to give a damn.
